# Is there any way to bind methods to a Go map other than temporarily assigning them to a variable?

Tags: go

this code works fine but the temp var used to call the function feels clunky

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    name  string
    value int
}

// SetName receives a pointer to Foo so it can modify it.
func (f *Foo) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}

var users = map[string]Foo{}

func main() {
    // Notice the Foo{}. The new(Foo) was just a syntactic sugar for &Foo{}
    // and we don't need a pointer to the Foo, so I replaced it.
    // Not relevant to the problem, though.
    //p := Foo{}
    users["a"] = Foo{value: 1}
    x := users["a"]
    x.SetName("Abc")
    users["a"] = x
    fmt.Println(users)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/vAXthNBfdP

Comment: Why does it feel clunky? It is more readable.

Comment: Your code is a little clunky, yes, but it's not clear what you are trying to do that makes it so.

Comment: @comeAndGo `x := users["a"] x.SetName("Abc") users["a"]=x` is more readable than `users["a"].SetName("Abc")`?

Comment: @JoeGauterin : Actually I suppose you're right, because by referencing users["a"] directly you would't need `users["a"]=x` ,Otherwise the extra line wouldn't bother me, if the variable was named `aFoo`instead of `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no. In Go **typically** pointers are transparent, and values get auto-addressed when you call pointer methods on them. You managed to find one of the few cases where they aren't. That case is map storage -- values in maps are not considered addressable. That is, you can never do `val := &map[key]`.

When you have a value `val := Typ{}` and methods defined on `*Typ`, when you try to call `val.Method()` Go will super secretly do `(&val).Method()`. Since you can't do `&map[key]`, then this doesn't work so that temporary variable dance you do is the only way.

As for why that's the case, the internals of a map are considered a bit secret to the user, since it's a hashmap it reserves the right to reallocate itself, shuffle around data, etc, allowing you to take the address of any value undermines that. There have been proposals considered to allow this **specific** case to work (that is: calling a method with a pointer receiver on it), since the fix is so easy, but none have been accepted yet. It may be allowed someday, but not right now.

Answer (score 1):

Following Jsor’s detailed explanation: if you really need to call methods of map values, it seems the only way for now is to use pointers for values.

```
var users = make(map[string]*Foo)

func main() {
    users["a"] = &Foo{value: 1}
    users["a"].SetName("Abc")
    fmt.Println(users["a"])
}
```

But that loses you, precisely, the ability to meaningfully print them (values are just memory addresses now). You’d need to write a custom printing function for `*Foo`:

```
func (f *Foo) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", *f)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/6-y2ewdnre